# Is there a way to only show specific subgroups of a pandas column when making a Pivot Table or Crosstab?

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to show the averages of weekly wages of specific jobs within my data set. One of the columns is titled "Department" and contains 16 unique values, but I only need 3 of these.

My current code is this:

```
pivot2 = pd.pivot_table(wage, index='Department', values='Weekly', aggfunc = ['mean'])
pivot2
```

'wage' is the name of my dataframe, 'Department' is the column I need to categorize by, and 'Weekly' is the column containing the weekly wages of each employee.

As of right now it returns something that looks like this and shows all of the unique values, but how would I make the table only show Marketing, Production, and Engineering?:
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/53L4n.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

aggfunc should be `aggfunc=np.mean`

Note: np comes from 'import numpy as np'

EDIT: I'm sorry, I didn't answer correctly, you should use the parameters `cols=[ "Marketing", "Production", "Engineering"]` on the pivot_table

Comment: Thank you for the note, but it does not really address the core question.

Comment: No worries! At a glance I can totally see how that would appear to be the main issue.

When I entered in your suggested code it returned:
"TypeError: pivot_table() got an unexpected keyword argument 'cols'"

Comment: depending on the version, it has to be either 'cols' or 'columns'

Comment: That returns "KeyError: 'Marketing'" :(

Comment: then that means they are the rows, use "rows" instead of columns

Comment: So this is how the code is looking as of now:
https://imgur.com/a/kJHxyuS
Thank you for your help on this by the way, it is greatly appreciated :)